# I want to send the option selected from dropdown to local storage and get it to display on another page, but its showing null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the dropdown in the 1st html page where 1 option is selected.

```
<body>
   <label for="select">Gender:</label>
   <select name="select" id="select">
     <option value = "0">Select</option>
     <option value = "1">Male</option>
     <option value = "2">Female</option>
     <option value = "3">Other</option>
   </select>
</body>
```

This is the script i'm using to store selected option in the local storage.

```
<script>
    var options = [];
    $("#select option").filter(":selected").each(function(index) {
      var option = $(this).text();
      options.push(option);
      $("#select").text(options.toString())

    });

    localStorage.setItem('select', options);
</script>
```

This is another page where i want to display the selected option.

```
<body>
  <p> Gender: <span id="display_select"></span></p>
</body>
```

This is the script to get the selected option from the local storage and display it on the 2nd page.Its showing null.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
     var options = localStorage.getItem("select");
     $("#display_select").text(options);
   }
});
```

Comment: could you put this code in a jsfiddle so we can try it?

Comment: if you write
console.log(option);
after 
var option = $(this).text();
does it output something in the console?

Comment: @totallytypicalcow No need for jsfiddle (or other off-site code).  Stack Overflow can run snippets which are the same thing, but they're embedded in the question.

Comment: Where do you do it when they change the value? All I see you doing is setting it on page load?

Comment: Trying this  $('#select').change(function(){
                localStorage.setItem('select', $(this).val());
     });
 but isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage only supports strings. For this to work you have to use JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse().

```
localStorage.setItem('select', JSON.stringify(options));

//...
var storedSelect = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('select'));
```

Your exemple to get a option selected:

```
$('#select').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('select', $('#select option:selected').text());
});

var select = localStorage.getItem('select');
$("#display_select").html(select);
```

Comment: U mean like this:  $('#select').change(function(){
                localStorage.setItem('select',  JSON.stringify($(this).val()));
             });

Comment: can you tell me how to do the same for check box:       <p id="qualifications">Qualifications:</p>

         <label for="checkbox1">BE</label>
         <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
         <label for="checkbox2">MCA</label>
         <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">

Answer (score 3):

The script you have for storing the select value doesn't actually do what you think it does.  What you need to do is have an event handler that runs when the select value changes and stores the value in `localStorage` at that point.  What you have simply runs once when the page is first loading.

```
$("#select").on("change", function() {
    localStorage.setItem('select', this.textContent);
});
```

Then to get the value later...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#display_select").text(localStorage.getItem("select"));
});
```

Comment: Seeing as they are using jQuery, might as well be consistent and use `$(this)`. **Update:** Not the down-voter.

Comment: @Script47 No - that would create a jQuery object that is completely unnecessary.  Besides, that's as the OP currently has it.

Comment: @Script47 Even when using jQuery we usually use it for the convenience of some of the features it offers but there is no need to add the overhead of wrapping `this` into a jQuery "wrapper" to query a native property for the sake of "consistency"

Comment: when im using  $("#display_select").val(localStorage.getItem("select")); nothing is showing.  When im using   $("#display_select").text(localStorage.getItem("select")); only value number is displayed.

Comment: Sorry for the faux pas - updated to `.val()` now.  That should work, assuming the select element actually has the options with the same values as before.

Comment: Its still not showing anything. Do we also have to convert options to string.

Comment: No, it's me assuming something incorrect.  I'll update it now.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your first script file where You store value,
       `var options = [];
       $(document).ready(function(){ 
             $('#select').change(function(){
                //console.log($(this).val());
               localStorage.setItem('select', $(this).val());
             });
   });`

Comment: In console the value number is showing. But in other page nothing is showing.

Comment: Other page you can get stored value using var select = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('select'));

Comment: Im doing it and then adding it to  :  $("#display_select").html(select);    but not working. Only number is showing.